# How to deploy a C# winform application with google.apis reference calls?

Tags: c#, winforms, google-api

I created a little desktop application to manage g-suite users in our school. The thing is that it only works on my pc.
On another (client) pc, I installed the application with a Setup-file (yes i 'think' all dependencies are included), but the application crashes on start:
   event : CLR20r3
   System.IO.FileNotFoundException

No details about what file is missing (otherwise I wouldn't be posting here)

When i remove all of the google api calls, the program is showing up correctly, so I'm pretty sure the google-api-runtime is missing on the client PC.

Reminds me of a missing client runtime, but i cannot find what I should install on the client PC. 
There is no sort of Google-api-client-runtime-installer on the net (like there are clients for database-connections) that would make deployment easier.

Any help will be appreciated with (eternal) recognition :)

Comment: Compare what is in the bin debug or release folder of your project to what the setup creates. You don't need the xml or pdg files but you should have all the same dll files at least.

Comment: Hi CrowCoder,
Your answer did help me a lot since copying all the output-files to the client-PC, the application started-up.
I'll have to find out why the installer project did not copied all dependencies!
Thanks to your help I can start digging a little further how to manage it from there.